# Connect a website on hosting server to my localhost phpmysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection, connection-string, web-hosting

> Just wandering if I can host my database locally for the website that is hosted on hosting provider's server. It means,
>
> > The web pages to be stored on hosting server.
> >     The database to be stored on localhost (phpMySql).

In summary, How can I point my website to use the localhost database?

Comment: For your website's point of view your *localhost* database is actually a *remote* one. This means you need a static ip or some DNS that points to your local machine. But for any purpose other than testing, this is a very bad idea both performance and security wise.

Answer (score 0):

As @Eggplant sais in his comment, you can set your php to use "remote server" and link it to your localhost.

For example see this tutorial how to link it:
http://www.danielmois.com/article/Manage_remote_databases_from_localhost_with_phpMyAdmin

But your localhost should have public IP address and should be always online for your website to work correctly.

**Not a good idea**, IMHO

Comment: I just want to set a test server on my laptop where i can play with all the code. So, basically won't be anything for public to visit and see. Anyway, Thanks a lot.

Comment: If your php and database server are in the same machine, there is no problem in using it. Just use **localhost** or **127.0.0.1** as server IP address

Comment: Thanks @DangeMask, I have used the databases in every other possible way except the one i have asked here. I am trying to get it done for a while now, but haven't got even any closer to it.

Comment: I'm little bit confused:
- Question: website on remote server, database on local machine
- Comment: test server on local machine... wchich server?

If you want to connect remote web server to local database, your PC needs to be publicky visible (public IP, opened firewall and so on).

Comment: I suggest starting even php server for testing on your PC. You can use for example WAMP.

Comment: Lets make it easy, I have no idea how I can connect my web pages (hosted on HostGator) to database (on my laptop: localhost).

Comment: That is the most difficult variant ;-)
As I said earlier, your laptop must be visible from the internet. If not, the website will never reach it to read from your database.
Yout need **public IP** from your internet provider and no NAT or any other network equipment (which will change your public IP to local one). There is only a little chance that your provider gave you public IP, so I suggest installing WAMP and testing everything on local copy of your website.